# Data structures for a 2D vector editor

Tags: editor, vector-graphics, shapes

I'm trying to make a simple 2D editor with the following capabilities:

- Create/delete rectangles, polygons, circles, etc
- Hierarchical grouping of these shapes
- Move, rotate, scale these shapes
- Apply a certain texture to them (with UV coordinates for each vertex)

I've had some success, but the code is messy. Are they any simple projects or articles that I can read to get some more info on the kinds of data structures used for such projects?

Comment: Did you actually design the application first, or just sit down and start writing code? Generally, the best way to write a clean code is to actually architect the system first.

Comment: @DemianBrecht, While logically sound, I usually find your suggestion impossible to follow. I usually hack together a rough draft first, and then use the experience gained to begin designing the second version. I find I can't design anything until I know how the pieces will work together. Maybe it's a Chicken/Egg thing.

Comment: @luser droog: You're describing the prototype stage and it's absolutely a valid part of the design flow. Prototype -> Technical Design -> Write code.

Comment: @DemianBrecht: Cool. I think we're in agreement. One shouldn't expect to achieve "clean code" in such a prototype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of literature out there to get good ideas from. Some good ones:

IEEE Tutorial: Computer Graphics '79 has all the important graphics algorithms from the 60s and 70s, many are the original articles.

Graphics Gems (I) surveys important techniques from the 80s.

You might also want to look at [PHIGS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phigs) which focuses on Hierarchical Graphics.

Answer (score 0):

Open Source 2D Game Engines can give you a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly "simple" in any sense, but [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org) might be worth looking at.